# why isn't node.js (Express) serving this route? and how do I fix it?

Tags: node.js, http-status-code-404

I'm writing an application and I'm trying to find out why this post route for login is not registering.

**If anyone has a better model for routes they can share or a solution to the problem please respond**

```html
import express from 'express';
const router = express.Router();

router.route('/login').post((req, res) => {
    console.log('login');
    let user = Users.getUser(req.body.email);

    if (!user) {
        console.log(`unable to find user: ${user}`);
        res.status(401).send('Unable to find username');
        return;
    }

    bcrypt.compare(req.body.pass, user.password, (err, goodComparison) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(401);
        } else if (goodComparison) {
            // Good password, generate key, send response
            let key = Sessions.generateSession(user, token => {
                let responseData = {
                    id: user.id,
                    username: user.username,
                    email: user.email,
                    admin: user.admin,
                    token: token
                };
                res.status(200).json(responseData);
            });
            // Invalid password
        } else {
            res.status(401);
        }
    });
});

export { router };
```

**console.log('login');** is never being called due to 404, the route is not being served.

```html
import express from 'express';

const router = express.Router();
import { router as loginRouter } from './routes/login.route';

/**
 * TODO:
 * Possibly automate routes, or json import
 */
export default {
    /** Initiate routers */
    registerRoutes: function() {
        console.log('registering routes');
        console.log(loginRouter);
        router.use('/login', loginRouter); /* HERE */
    }
};
```

in my app.js (yes it's being properly imported)

```
// Register routes
```

```html
// Register routes
Routes.registerRoutes();
```

**my app is 404ing the post for /login, but if I put the routing code directly in app.js it works**

If this is an issue with the way I'm exporting the route or handling the routing or anything, I've done a lot of searching online for a solution and haven't been able to find it. Suggestions and solutions are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The router created in your second code block with `const router = express.Router();` is never hooked up to anything.  It needs to be hooked to an express instance that is attached to an http server.

Just calling `router.use(...)` by itself does not cause anything to to anything.  That router has to be hooked to an Express instance which is itself hooked to an http server that has been started for incoming http requests to get sent to the router.

---

In addition, it appears you're also trying to create a route for `/login/login` rather than just `/login`.  When you do this:

```
router.use('/login', loginRouter);
```

That says that whatever requests are send to `router`, filter out the request so that only requests that start with `/login` are sent to `loginRouter`.  Then, inside of `loginRouter`, you have this:

```
router.route('/login').post(...)
```

which says that for requests that came to `router` (which is actually `loginRouter` from the previous code), look for an additional path of `/login` on whatever was already matched.  That means you would be looking for `/login/login` which is probably not what you're posting to.

---

FYI, your code is a lot harder to follow when you use different symbolic names for the same router in different files.  If you're going to use `loginRouter` in one place, then for that specific router, use that same name in all your files.  Your code will be a lot less confusing and a lot less likely for someone to make a mistake.  You call it `loginRouter` in one place and `router` in another.  And, you then have other routers that you also call `router`.  Very confusing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed and hasty response, do  you have any suggestions how I would mount my routes to the http server or preferably a github  project with anexample of routes done well in es6, I've searched a lot and been unable to find an es6 project with routes done well.

Comment: @z21 - I don't have a specific tutorial to recommend.  I always say to start simple, get simple things working in one file, then move some code to a new file and make sure you are exporting the exact same thing you were using previously and break a piece of functionality into a new module file.  I see lots of newbies start with 10 files and a hierarchical file structure and get all confused.  You can't see the forest through the trees when you start complicated.  You don't need to start that complicated.  You can always spin code out into a new module file if a file gets too large.

Comment: @z21 - And, for some reason, node.js developers seem to think they can't have more than about 100 lines of code or a couple routes in a source file.  There's is no such requirement at all.  Keep things simple until you have a good reason to make things less simple.  And, the more experience you get, the better equipped you will be to know what to break into another file and how to do it and/or how to debug it when things go wrong.